# How to create Windows Service with unknown periodicity?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, service, gps

The task is to create Windows Service which should periodically connect to the SQL Server database (it contains GPS data from hundreds or thousands of cars), read data from the table, process it and write result to another table.
The problem is that depends on how much data are there in the database processing time can vary from milliseconds to several hours.

If there are a lot of data it should wait until previous processing will end and then start another iteration.

If there are not much data it should accumulate at least 500 GPS records, process it and start new iteration.
Please provide your examples with C#.

P.S.
Processing of GPS data means generating complex car events, for example, defining car overspeed, stop points, entering specific geographical zone and so on...
From the algorithmic point of view generating some of these events can be resource intensive.

P.P.S 
I have already create it but as console application with infinite cycle, but I'm new to windows services and I don't know how to realize such functionality as windows service correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would

- create a watchdog service that checks if the processing
  application is running every X seconds/minutes/hours (depending on
  how often you want to process the data).
- If it is running then wait until the next scheduled event time and check again.
- If it's not running then start the processing application.

Comment: I'd suggest you do some research on that. We're not here to provide working solutions to broad problems but if you have a ***specific*** problem when trying to implement the watchdog service you are most welcome to ask a new question.